# How to tweet with multiple # tag in android?

Tags: android, twitter

i want tweet on twitter using # tag.

For example

My text #tag you like it #tag2 and my website.

This is my tweet text and when i call this data using Uri.

```
String finalTweet = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=webclient&text=" + "&hashtags=" + Name
                    + " Im Share &hashtags=" + Title
                    + " @text – link to "
                    + someURL;
mIntent.setData(Uri.parse(finalTweet));
startActivity(mIntent);
```

This is my code for post data using Uri.when i post this data via intent i got only this.

My text #tag.
My string cut when i post on twitter.

Answer (score 0):

i solve my problem after using this code replace of # see below data for Uri format.

```
url = new String(url.trim().replace(" ", "%20").replace("&", "%26")
.replace(",", "%2c").replace("(", "%28").replace(")", "%29")
.replace("!", "%21").replace("=", "%3D").replace("<", "%3C")
.replace(">", "%3E").replace("#", "%23").replace("$", "%24")
.replace("'", "%27").replace("*", "%2A").replace("-", "%2D")
.replace(".", "%2E").replace("/", "%2F").replace(":", "%3A")
.replace(";", "%3B").replace("?", "%3F").replace("@", "%40")
.replace("[", "%5B").replace("\\", "%5C").replace("]", "%5D")
.replace("_", "%5F").replace("`", "%60").replace("{", "%7B")
.replace("|", "%7C").replace("}", "%7D"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
    URLEncoder.encode(url.trim(), "UTF-8");